# Resilience4j vs Hystrix. What would be the best for fault tolerance?

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix, circuit-breaker, fault-tolerance, resilience4j

When I initially learn about spring boot, I've learnt about `spring cloud netflix hystrix` as a circuit breaker. There were bunch of options such as multiple application properties and annotation base declarations for fault tolerance. In-addition to that, it has few important threshold values as well. Most importantly `hystrix` the data can be prompted to `hystrix dashboard` via `hystrix streams`. With the use of `turbine` we can combine multiple `hystrix streams` and overview microservices. That is my experience from `hystrix`.

Now I have a requirement to implement `Resilience4j` which is basically supporting the same behaviour for fault tolerance. I am new to `Resilience4j` and I would like to know the main difference of these two fault tolerance options before getting started. According to my research `Resilience4j` is a robust option than `hystrix`. I would be grateful to know the expert facts and thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can say it really does not matter which implementation you choose unless there are specific requirements that would favor a particular implementation. I would not pick anything from Netflix Hystrix as it is in maintenance mode as of 2018 (https://spring.io/blog/2018/12/12/spring-cloud-greenwich-rc1-available-now). Read the Hystrix status at GitHub: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix#hystrix-status.

Let me emphasize this: *"What I find more important from the architectural point of view is to enable an environment where it is easy to replace such implementation as needed."*

I can recommend using [**Spring Cloud Circuit Breaker**](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker) as a framework that has a consistent API and allows developers to pick the implementation: Netflix Hystrix, reactive or non-reactive Resilience4j, Sentinel, and Spring Retry.

All can be configured as necessary, and all provide a basic default configuration to change value thresholds, slow call thresholds, sliding window size, etc.

Answer (score 6):

> The most prominent difference between the two is the fact that while
> Hystrix embraces an Object-Oriented design where calls to external
> systems have to be wrapped in a HystrixCommand offering multiple
> functionalities, Resilience4J relies on function composition to let
> you stack the specific decorators you need.

*Source:* [Circuit Breaker Pattern: Migrating From Hystrix to Resilience4J](https://www.exoscale.com/syslog/migrate-from-hystrix-to-resilience4j/)

---

Resilience4J is a standalone library inspired by Hystrix but build on the principles of Functional Programming. Resilience4J will be the best option to handle *fault tolerance*.